# How to get value from multidimensional array and put it into comparison in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I've faced a problem and I don't know how to solve it correctly.

I have multidimensional array and I want to fetch the certain value from this array and put it to the new array. See example below:

```
var myArr = [];
var extArr = [{ name:"john", id:1 }, { name: "bill", id: 2 }, ... , { name: "john", id: N }, ... ];

$.each(extArr, function(key, val){
    if (  ...  ) { // <-- I need a condition here to prevent "name" repetition
        myArr.push({ name: val.name, id: val.id });
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

I need to find the condition to prevent pushing into *myArr* the same names. For example I don't want to have two *johns* or more than one *bill* in *myArr*.

All I can think of is to launch a new *$.each* loop for *myArr* like this:

```
$.each(extArr, function(key, val){
    var checkcheck;
    $.each(myArr, function(key, name){
       if ( val.name == name.name ) {
           checkcheck = false;
       } else {
           checkcheck = true;
       }
    }
    if (  checkcheck == false  ) {
        myArr.push({ name: val.name, id: val.id });
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

But I'm sure there's gotta be a much more smarter solution for this.
Please help me find it ...

Comment: Please decide what you're asking before you post the question. Your edit radically changes the solutions.

Comment: sorry ... It's a real hard time for me to form all this stuff in my head. Believe me, I'm doing my best right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check if the value already exists:

```
$.each(extArr, function(key, val){
    if ( $.inArray(val.name, myArr) == -1) 
         myArr.push(val.name);
});
```

Comment: you're absolutely right ... I knew about the `$.inArray` stuff and I saw your reply and I understood that I've made a misstake in the question.  `myArr` is also multidimensional. Now I've fixed it. Please check

Comment: Now you still have a regular array, but it contains objects, and you'll need to iterate each object and get the name value, and check if it matches the current name etc. pretty much what you're already doing.

Comment: yes it actually works, but I just wanted to check if there's any other solution to do this? For example if `extArr` is 1000 items and `myArr` also 1000 items ... it's a 1000000 values check ... I'm not sure if it's cool